# asp.net including javascript slow on iss

Tags: javascript, performance, iis

I am facing very strange situation. I am developing my `ASP.NET` application and debugging it on visual studio development server and when I some component is finished, I publish my application on IIS to let other people test the input data. So when I am running it on dev. server, everything is fine, but on IIS the page loading is incredible slow.

So first question is **How can be compiled application slower then application in debug mode?**

I wanted to find out why, so I started to remove JavaScript includes from my `site.master.cs` file. And It actually helped, but it works in unexpected way.

My includes are done by this code :

```
ClientScriptManager cs =Page.ClientScript;
        cs.RegisterClientScriptInclude(typeof(string), "jquery", Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"));
        cs.RegisterClientScriptInclude(typeof(string), "jqueryUI", Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"));
        cs.RegisterClientScriptInclude(typeof(string), "utility", Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/utility.js"));
        cs.RegisterClientScriptInclude(typeof(string), "forms_v2", Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/forms_v2.js"));
        cs.RegisterClientScriptInclude(typeof(string), "odkazy", Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/odkazy.js"));
        cs.RegisterClientScriptInclude(typeof(string), "tabs_v2", Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/tabs_v2.js"));  //Nahradí tabs
        cs.RegisterClientScriptInclude(typeof(string), "user", Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/user.js"));
        cs.RegisterClientScriptInclude(typeof(string), "grafika", Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/grafika.js"));
        cs.RegisterClientScriptInclude(typeof(string), "json2", Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/json2.js"));//IE7
```

So by removing includes one by one I have found out that the problem is caused only by `forms_v2.js`  but I can't simply remove this script, I need to find out exactly which function slows my app down. But after removing whole text in the script, nothing changes.

So  finally the situation is this: when there is include for `forms_v2.js` even if it's empty file, my app is very slow, but when this include is removed, everything works fine.

P.S. I know that to improve performance its better to have less JS files and I will merge it and minify before deploying, so that's not my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check existing of these script before including

```
if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("jquery"))
      Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(typeof(string), "jquery", "YOUR_SCRIPT");
```

Comment: Yeah, I think that helped, thanks. But I don't know why exactly, could you explain, how it works? I thought the server to update script when is already registered.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure exactly, but I think it just put another block of the same script which is not good.